# Linq to SQL error - Member Access not legal. What is causing this?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to use Linq To Sql and have hit a problem when attempting to execute the following query in my web application:

```
var query = from t in teamsTable
            where t.SeasonTeams.All(x => x.SeasonID != 4)
            select t;

return query.ToList();
```

At this point, i receive the following error:

> Member access 'Int32 SeasonID' of
>   'DomainModel.Entities.SeasonTeam' not
>   legal on type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[DomainModel.Entities.SeasonTeam].

Using LINQPad, the exact same query works. I've included the classes with Linq Mappings below.  I'd really appreciate some help both solving the problem and explaining what is causing it.

```
[Table(Name = "Teams")]
public class Team
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int TeamID { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Association(OtherKey = "TeamID")]
    private EntitySet<Player> _players = new EntitySet<Player>();
    public IList<Player> TeamPlayers { get { return _players.ToList(); } }


    [Association(OtherKey = "HomeTeamID")]
    private EntitySet<Fixture> _homeFixtures = new EntitySet<Fixture>();
    public IList<Fixture> HomeFixtures { get { return _homeFixtures.ToList(); } }

    [Association(OtherKey = "AwayTeamID")]
    private EntitySet<Fixture> _awayFixtures = new EntitySet<Fixture>();
    public IList<Fixture> AwayFixtures { get { return _awayFixtures.ToList(); } }

    [Association(OtherKey="TeamID")]
    private EntitySet<SeasonTeam> _seasonteams = new EntitySet<SeasonTeam>();
    public IList<SeasonTeam> SeasonTeams { get { return _seasonteams.ToList(); } }

}

[Table(Name = "Seasons")]
public class Season
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int SeasonID { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public int LeagueID { get; set; }

    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(OtherKey = "SeasonID")]
    private EntitySet<Fixture> _fixtures = new EntitySet<Fixture>();
    public IList<Fixture> Fixtures { get { return _fixtures.ToList().AsReadOnly(); } }

    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(OtherKey = "SeasonID")]
    private EntitySet<SeasonTeam> _seasonteams = new EntitySet<SeasonTeam>();
    public IList<SeasonTeam> SeasonTeams { get { return _seasonteams.ToList().AsReadOnly(); } }

    internal EntityRef<League> _league;
    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Association(ThisKey = "LeagueID", Storage = "_league")]
    public League League
    {
        get { return _league.Entity; }
        internal set { _league.Entity = value; LeagueID = value.LeagueID; }
    }
}


[Table(Name="SeasonTeams")]
public class SeasonTeam
{
    [Column(IsDbGenerated = true, IsPrimaryKey = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int SeasonTeamID { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public int TeamID { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public int SeasonID { get; set; }

    internal EntityRef<Team> _team;
    [Association(ThisKey = "TeamID", Storage = "_team")]
    public Team Team
    {
        get { return _team.Entity; }
        set { _team.Entity = value; TeamID = value.TeamID; }
    }

    internal EntityRef<Season> _season;
    [Association(ThisKey = "SeasonID", Storage = "_season")]
    public Season Season
    {
        get { return _season.Entity; }
        set { _season.Entity = value; SeasonID = value.SeasonID; }
    }
}
```

Comment: it almost sounds like you might be missing a using statement, since it looks like your Linq is resolving to Linq to objects instead of Linq to SQL

Comment: What the hell generated that Linq2SQL? It looks very wrong.

Comment: @leppie - could you elaborate please?

Comment: Use the DBML designer in VS and see what gets generated for a normal database.

Comment: i chagned my approach and started using the code generated by SQLMetal for now

Comment: @Temple - did you ever figure this out? I am getting a similar error...